# so im trying to make a cps tester and i had a few problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

All the text is on the left and even if i put the position to top it still is stuck at the bottom

and im not even 1% done and i have millions of problems.

and i made it so every time you click it is supposed to go up 1 but it is still 0 when you click.

this is the code.

```
<title>CPS Tester</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let clicks = int(0)
    elem = document.getElementById("numClicks").innerHTML
        = var clicks
</script>

<style>

    @font-face{
        font-family: font;
        src:url('assets/font.ttf')  format('truetype')
    }

    div.clickhere{
        text-align: left;
        position: top;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    div.stats {
        text-align: right;
        font-family: "font";
        position: top;
        z-index: 1;
        background-position-y: 0;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="clickhere">
    <img src="assets/button1.png" onclick="click();">
</div>

<div class="stats">
    <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <p>You have clicked <span id=numClicks>0</span> times.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var click = int(0); 
    clickhere.onclick=click(){click ++;}
    
    function start {
        let clicks = int(0)
        document.getElementById("numClicks").innerHTML 
            = var clicks
    }

    function click() {
        var clicks = var clicks + int(1)
        document.getElementById("numClicks").innerHTML
            = var clicks
    }

    function calculatecps(inclicks, seconds) {
        var cps = inclicks / seconds
        return cps
    }   

</script>
```

[screw this css, its top but it shows up at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ADS8.png)

Comment: Is `position: top` a valid CSS property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

`position: top` is not a valid CSS property.

Instead, use this: `position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px`

Which would put it in the top right corner.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).